# Stimulsoft .net 6 не может загрузить отчет

Tags: .net, stimulsoft

Есть задача, открывать в приложении на .net7 отчёт `Stimulsoft`. Отчёт в виде mrt-файла с содержимым в json.

Использую стандартные библиотеки от `Stimulsoft`. При попытке открыть отчёт получаю исключение
`Stimulsoft.Base.Serializing.StiDashboardNotSupportedException`. Глянул в декомпилированных исходниках, такое происходит при чтении страниц отчёта. Если данные из секции страниц не получается преобразовать в `StiPage`, то получаем данное исключение.
Установлен пакет `Stimulsoft.Reports.Engine.NetCore`.

Сталкивался ли кто с подобным и как забороть?

Answer (score 0):

Выяснилось, что есть `report`, а есть `dashboard`.
Первый загружается так:

```
StiReport report = new StiReport();
report.Load(...);
```

а, `dashboard`:

```
StiReport report = StyReport.CreateDashboard();
report.Load(...);
```